# Solr can't find config file despite beeing exiting

Tags: solr

I have changed some rights within a new core (solr 7.7.1) I am trying to configure. That has now led to failing to start the core on solr start. The rights look allright to me and everything else as well. Not different to other cores.

The error msg:

```
SolrCore Initialization Failures
test: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core test: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/test/conf/solrconfig.xml
Please check your logs for more information
```

log:

```
core test is not available due to init failure: Could not load conf for core test: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/test/conf/solrconfig.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1644)
```

The file itself:

```
ls -ls /var/solr/data/test/conf/solrconfig.xml
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 solr solr 71 Mar 25 09:52 /var/solr/data/test/conf/solrconfig.xml -> /home/www/test/solrconfig.xml
```

Looks 1:1 with another core config. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check, if the file `/home/www/test/solrconfig.xml` exits
2. Find out, under which user account solr is running. Use something like `ps -efa | grep solr` and check, if this user has access to  `/home/www/test/solrconfig.xml`
3. If `/var/solr/data/test/conf/solrconfig.xml` and `/home/www/test/solrconfig.xml` resists at the same filesystem: try to use hardlinks instead of softlinks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried all those, but eventually only succeeded by doing a copy of the entire conf folder of another core to that core and changing the files again. Could not track down the problem in an apropriate time frame.